# Is there quick access to network settings such as Wifi, 3G and bluetooth?

Tags: iphone, settings

As titled, is there any way to access settings mentioned in the title without going into Settings app everytime?

iPhone not jailbroken, running iOS 5.0.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a website ( http://brdrck.me/settings/ ). But this will only work with iOS <= 5.0.1.

Comment: This should work. but not with 5.1

Comment: I think @revolver is suggesting that it will work now (Less than or equal to 5.0.1), but it will stop working come 5.1, if current developer builds are anything to go by.  I suspect the same applies to my answer using Launch Center.

Answer (score 1):

Actually there is a way.  Using a 3rd party app like [Launch Center](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/launch-center-schedule-shortcuts/id488626436?mt=8&ign-mpt=uo=4) [(review)](http://lifehacker.com/5879611/launch-center-adds-handy-app-and-settings-shortcuts-to-notification-center) allows you to add custom URL shortcuts using application URL schemas for a number of 3rd party apps, as well as some built in ones including Settings.

These are the settings shortcuts you can use:

```
    About – prefs:root=General&path=About
Accessibility – prefs:root=General&path=ACCESSIBILITY
 Airplane Mode On – prefs:root=AIRPLANE_MODE
 Auto-Lock – prefs:root=General&path=AUTOLOCK
Brightness – prefs:root=Brightness
Bluetooth – prefs:root=General&path=Bluetooth
Date & Time – prefs:root=General&path=DATE_AND_TIME
FaceTime – prefs:root=FACETIME
General – prefs:root=General
 Keyboard – prefs:root=General&path=Keyboard
 iCloud – prefs:root=CASTLE
 iCloud Storage & Backup – prefs:root=CASTLE&path=STORAGE_AND_BACKUP
International – prefs:root=General&path=INTERNATIONAL
Location Services – prefs:root=LOCATION_SERVICES
 Music – prefs:root=MUSIC
Music Equalizer – prefs:root=MUSIC&path=EQ
Music Volume Limit – prefs:root=MUSIC&path=VolumeLimit
 Network – prefs:root=General&path=Network
 Nike + iPod – prefs:root=NIKE_PLUS_IPOD
 Notes – prefs:root=NOTES
Notification – prefs:root=NOTIFICATIONS_ID
 Phone – prefs:root=Phone
Photos – prefs:root=Photos
 Profile – prefs:root=General&path=ManagedConfigurationList
 Reset – prefs:root=General&path=Reset
Safari – prefs:root=Safari
Siri – prefs:root=General&path=Assistant
Sounds – prefs:root=Sounds
Software Update – prefs:root=General&path=SOFTWARE_UPDATE_LINK
Store – prefs:root=STORE
 Twitter – prefs:root=TWITTER
 Usage – prefs:root=General&path=USAGE
VPN – prefs:root=General&path=Network/VPN
 Wallpaper – prefs:root=Wallpaper
Wi-Fi – prefs:root=WIFI
```

And there are a number of 3rd party ones which are available just by having them installed on the same device as Launch Center, allowing you to for example tweet using clipboard contents, open Facebook app at the notifications screen, search ebay using clipboard contents and so on.

Basically [any app with a URL scheme](http://appcubby.com/apps/) can be used by Launchbar, although the settings app isn't listed as I think it's kinda supposed to be unofficial, but creating a custom action using the above links works a dream.  Some of the links above just take you to the screen, others (like Airplane Mode) take you there and actually flip the switch for you.  Most useful.

The other answer referencing http://brdrck.me/settings/ effectively used a very similar method, but placed a custom webclip icon per shortcut referencing the required URL schema into your home screen, and the ability was removed for some reason.  This still needs you to start Launch Center, but at least you can collect alll your shortcuts there and place it on your dock for quick access, without needing a screen of individual shortcut icons that you need to scroll to anyway.

My first home screen consists of Launch Center, and nothing else.  Note: Other apps can do this also, I just have experience with this one.

Comment: This capability seems to have been removed by Apple in iOS 11. Launch Center is still useful for launching other actions, but there’s no accesss to Wi-Fi or Bluetooth settings.

Answer (score 0):

Ultimately there is no way while using native iOS.

As I'm sure you already know, when there is available wifi's in the area (and you aren't connected to one) it will come up with a list of wifi's in your area. If you have a bluetooth headset that is already paired, one can just turn the headset on and it will automatically connect. Again, I'm sure this is nothing new.